# Where is SpringBootServletInitializer's DispatcherServlet?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How SpringBootServletInitializer determines RootConfig.class, WebConfig.class, and maps DispatcherSevlet?

Comment: @AutoConfiguration annotation do this job. It gives a hint to spring what best configuration should be loaded on the basis of defaults accepted by community.

Answer (score 3):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

`return application.sources(Application.class);` - loads the Application.class. That's your main configuration, where you can declare `@Bean`s. You can add more `@Configuration` classes by putting  them in the same folder, for example, and they will be "component-scanned".

If you declare a `@Configuration` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, you have an access to the web configuration like resource handlers, argument resolvers, etc.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/public-resources/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(1, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>   argumentResolvers) {
         argumentResolvers.add(new FooBarHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

By default the dispatcher servlet is configured to the root path "/"
If you need more details, see the [auto configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.java).

Comment: You don't need `@EnableWebMvc` in that case - in fact, adding that annotation switches off the whole MVC Boot auto-configuration.

Comment: @BrianClozel You're right. Forgot about that. Thanks, answer edited.